# jQuery select2 - unable to move through form using TAB

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to make `select2` to open when focused using TAB key. I have found several suggestions on stackoverflow, however they weren't working for me. Finally, I have come with this solution (https://jsfiddle.net/shimon001/k06g0tgj/6/):

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="h3">Open select2 on focus</h1>

      <p>Click on the email input then use tab to change to select2 field. You will notice that select2 dropdown doesn't open.</p>
      <form action="#">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
        <br>
        <label for="select2">Here is select2</label>
        <select class="form-control js-select" multiple="multiple">
          <option value="1">Option A</option>
          <option value="2">Option B</option>
          <option value="3">Option C</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Name">
        <br>
        <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Surname">
        <br>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.js-select').select2({
  placeholder: "Select",
  width: "100%",
  multiple: false
});

$('.js-select').on('select2:open', function(){
    console.log('opened');
});

$('.container').on('keyup', 'form', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  e.stopPropagation();

  if (keyCode == 9) {
    console.log('TAB');
    var focused = document.activeElement;
    console.log(focused);
    if ($(focused).hasClass('select2-selection')) {
      console.log('has class');
      $(focused).closest('.select2').prev().select2('open');
    }

  }
});
```

I can make the `select2` open when focused using TAB key, **but then I am unable to traverse further through the form using TAB key**.

I tried to check which element is focused after the `select2` element and it's the `body` element. I suppose this is becouse the focus steps out of the form when the `select2` box is opened.

Any suggestions what could be done, to ste on next element in form after leaving the `select2` box?

Thanks
shimon

Comment: Any update on this or are you lucky to resolved this. I am facing the same issue for TAB traverse. Please let me know if you got resolution.

Comment: @KalpeshSatasiya - unfortunately I didn't use this way of opening the select2 with TAB key. It's now accessible only via mouse click.